# Help With Browser Testing

Tags: testing, browser

I've tried browsershots.org but it's a bit overwhelming. Surely I don't need to test *that* many browsers?

Is there any way I can just test the top five or the top ten browser-OS combinations?

Sorry, I'm new to this! Thanks,

Tara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try adobe browser lab - https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore results for browsers you don't want to support.